# Does PayPal use the same Transaction ID when Retrying failed payments?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm building a recurring/subscription payment system with PayPal and all is going well.

Can anyone share the IPN data for when PayPal sends a retry payment? Specifically I need to know if paypal is going to use the same txn_id, or generate a new one every time it retries?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should receive a new transaction id everytime a payment is processed. You can test this by setting up a recurring payment in the sandbox, and setting it to bill daily.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! Seems strange that they would do that with Failed payments (create a new one every time) but I'll test it out!

Comment: I apologize, I miss understood your question. You will only get transaction id's for successful transactions. You would not get a transaction id for failed payments.

Comment: Oh no worries, I finally found the IPN area in the Sandbox site so I was able to actually start receiving them properly.